# StructureMap 4 constructor dependency with named instance

Tags: c#, ioc-container, structuremap, constructor-injection

I want to implement the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) using StructureMap 4.
I've created an interface `IDeveloper` and two implementations
`CSharpDeveloper` which is the decorated type, and `DeveloperDecorator`
which is the decorator. 
The decorator type has a dependency on `IDeveloper` and the class itself implements `IDevloper`, which means that one of the types should be a named instance.
The named instance is `CSharpDeveloper`

```
public interface IDeveloper
{
}

public class CSharpDeveloper : IDeveloper
{
}

public class DeveloperDecorator : IDeveloper
{
    private readonly IDeveloper developer = null;

    public DeveloperDecorator(IDeveloper developer) {
        this.developer = developer;
    }
}
```

I want to register the DeveloperDecorator as an `IDeveloper` that I could resolve the type using unnamed GetInstance overload function

```
container.GetInstance<IDeveloper>();
```

and StructureMap will be able to resolve the dependent type as the named instance. Something like this (concept code)

```
Func<IDeveloper> factory = () => {
    return new DeveloperDecorator(container.GetInstance<IDeveloper>("name"));
};
```

**I can't use generics at all** so I can not use the `Ctor<TCtorType>()` api.
I have a type called `TypeMap` which contains the service type, concrete type and optional name.

```
public class TypeMap
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type ServiceType { get; set; }
    public Type ConcreteType { get; set; }
}
```

and I've tried to use Dependencies but nothing worked.

```
public void Register(TypeMap typeMap, ITypeMapCollection dependencies = null) {
    container.Configure(x => {
        var use = x.For(typeMap.ServiceType)
                   .Add(typeMap.ConcreteType);

        if (typeMap.Name.IsNotNullOrEmpty()) {
            use.Named(typeMap.Name);
        }

        if (dependencies.IsNotNullOrEmpty()) {
            dependencies.ForEach(dependency => {
                use.Dependencies.Add(dependency.Name, dependency.ServiceType);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do so by supplying the Use method an expression tree that creates the instance and resolve all dependencies by the container.

```
public void Register(TypeMap typeMap, ITypeMapCollection dependencies = null) {
    container.Configure(x => {
        var use = x.For(typeMap.ServiceType)
                   .Use(typeMap.ConcreteType);

        if (typeMap.Name.IsNotNullOrEmpty()) {
            use.Named(typeMap.Name);
        }

        if (dependencies.IsNotNullOrEmpty()) {
            x.For(typeMap.ServiceType).Use("composite", BuildExpression(typeMap, dependencies));
        }
    });
}

private Func<IContext, object> BuildExpression(TypeMap typeMap, ITypeMapCollection dependencies) {
    var contextParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IContext), "context");
    var @params = dependencies.ToArray(d => d.ServiceType);
    var ctorInfo = typeMap.ConcreteType.GetConstructor(@params);
    var genericMethodInfo = typeof(IContext).GetMethods().First(method => {
        return method.Name.Equals("GetInstance") &&
                method.IsGenericMethodDefinition &&
                method.GetParameters().Length == 1;
    });

    var getInstanceCallExpressions = dependencies.Select(dependency => {
        var nameParam = Expression.Constant(dependency.Name, typeof(string));
        var methodInfo = genericMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { dependency.ServiceType });

        return Expression.Call(contextParameter, methodInfo, new[] { nameParam });
    });

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IContext, object>>(
                    Expression.New(ctorInfo, getInstanceCallExpressions),
                    contextParameter);

    return lambda.Compile();
}
```